# Why my js code can't recognize html unicode?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a scroll-down effect by taking reference of this code snippet.

https://codepen.io/1csyu/pen/eYvmKWJ?editors=1010

I want to add a down arrow to the button. The unicode of the arrow is Hex2193. I searched insert method into html and js code as shown below. But my js code can't recognize it. Would anyone please let me know what have I done wrong? Thank you so much.

```
**html**

<div class="scroll-btn-container">
    <button class="scroll-btn">Show More &#x2193;</button>
</div>

**js**

var downA = '\u2193';


function toggleDescriptionHeight(e) {
    ele.classList.toggle('expanded');
    if (e.target.innerHTML === 'Show More' + downA) {
        e.target.innerHTML = 'Show Less' + downA;
    } else {
        e.target.innerHTML = 'Show More' + downA;
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use innerHTML for checking the value/state of it, add/remove class/data to the element instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it this way

```
**html**

<div class="scroll-btn-container">
    <button class="scroll-btn">Show More &#x2193;</button>
</div>

**js**

function toggleDescriptionHeight(e) {
    ele.classList.toggle('expanded');
    if (e.target.innerHTML.includes('Show More')) {
        e.target.innerHTML = 'Show Less ▲';
    } else {
        e.target.innerHTML = 'Show More ▼';
    }
}
```

You can just copy and paste the symbols inside a JS String or store the symbol directly in the variable. There is no need of unicode.
You can find all unicode symbols directly at https://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: He didn't. This is just for showing his code.

Comment: Oh my goodness I have been working on this for an hour. Atheesh you solved my problem in a min after I post here. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome! Request you to accept the answer (upvote if possible).